# Connect Windows virtual machine to my local network

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I had this working for the last couple of years, but today I updated to Windows 10 and I guess the settings got removed and now I have a problem. So I have a private network, 192.168.0.0/24 . I have a few laptops and other things connected, as well, I have a virtual machine running inside on vmware. This virtual machine needs to be accessed by my other machines on the network so it needs a local IP address (Inside the vm it is set as 192.168.0.100). The problem now is when I turn on the machine it says it does not have access. Inside of the VMWare settings I have the network connection set as Custom and it has VMnet1 selected. I remember a couple of years ago I set up something inside of my host machine to enable vmnet1 to work, but I have googled now, but can't find what I did exactly previously to make it work. So simply I need my virtual machine (windows 7) running inside of my host (Windows 10) to look like just another computer on the network so my other machines can communicate with it.

I have tried working with the virtual network editor where I put VMnet1 as host only and then in my physical adapter's properties allowed sharing, but I can't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the VM to be on the same physical network as the host, you should set the VMnet mode to [bridged](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/vmware-server-workstation-player-articles/understanding-virtual-networking-vmware-workstation-9.html) in the network editor, not host-only, neither NAT.